# Breadcrumbs not showing the home and category names

Tags: magento2.2.6, product-page, breadcrumbs

Breadcrumbs is not showing the home ,category names in product details page.

It shows Only Product name. How do I resolve it,Please provide me a solution

In latest version 2.3.3 also same issue only showing Home > Product name Not

showing Name of category before product name

```
Like : https://prnt.sc/qg9rnb
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/ThemeName/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="XXX\Breadcrumbs\Block\Breadcrumbs" name="product.view.breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml" />       
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

**In app/design/frontend/VendorTheme/ThemeName/Magento_Theme/templates/html/breadcrumbs.phtml:**

```
<?php $crumbs = $block->getBreadcrumb(); ?>
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
        <ul class="items">
            <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
                <li class="item <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbName ?>">
                    <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**In App/Code/XXX/Breadcrumbs/Block/Breadcrumbs.php:**

```
<?php

namespace XXX\Breadcrumbs\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class Breadcrumbs extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs
{

    /**
     * Catalog data
     *
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $_catalogData = null;
    protected $path = array();

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Data $catalogData
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(Context $context, Data $catalogData, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_catalogData = $catalogData;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getTitleSeparator($store = null)
    {
        $separator = (string) $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('catalog/seo/title_separator', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store);
        return ' ' . $separator . ' ';
    }

    public function getBreadcrumb()
    {
        $this->addCrumb(
                'home', [
            'label' => __('Home'),
            'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
            'link' => $this->getBaseUrl()
                ]
        );
        foreach ((array) $this->path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
            $this->addCrumb($name, $breadcrumb);
        }
        return $this->getCrumbs();
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->path = $this->_catalogData->getBreadcrumbPath();
        $title = [];
        foreach ((array) $this->path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
            $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
        }
        return $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(join($this->getTitleSeparator(), array_reverse($title)));
        //return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCrumbs()
    {
        return $this->_crumbs;
    }

    public function getBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
    }

}
```

If you got it, let me know.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact path where I need to put these codes

Comment: I update exact path where I need to put these codes

Comment: I tried this and got 2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: XXX\Breadcrumbs\Block\Breadcrumbs
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class XXX\Breadcrumbs\Block\Breadcrumbs does not exist

Comment: Confirmed that this is still working in Magento 2.3.5-p1. Make sure that within the catalog_product_view.xml the Block Template points to Magento_Theme and not XXX_Breadcrumbs though

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VedoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Theme::html/breadcrumbs.phtml" />
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Breadcrumbs" />
    </body>
</page>
```